# Object.assign() - weird behaviour need explanation

Tags: javascript, object, assign

I've got this code:

```js
function margeOptions(options, passedOptions) {
  options = Object.assign(options, passedOptions); 
}

let passedOpts = {a: true};
let opts = {a: false};

margeOptions(opts, passedOpts); 
console.log(opts); // as expected returns {a: true}
```

but when I change function a little bit, like this:

```js
function margeOptions(options, passedOptions) {
  options = Object.assign({}, options, passedOptions); 
}

let passedOpts = {a: true};
let opts = {a: false};

margeOptions(opts, passedOpts); 
console.log(opts); // this time returns {a: false} <-- !
```

So what really happened in here?

Comment: `formal_parameter = ` in a function doesn't affect the actual parameter in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object.assign()` function modifies the contents of the first object parameter. Thus in the first function:

```
options = Object.assign(options, passedOptions);
```

your code works because `options` is the first parameter. Note that the assignment back to the `options` parameter has no effect, or at least no useful effect. It will assign the return value of `Object.assign` to the `options` variable, but that's the value it already has.

The second function passes a newly-constructed empty object as the first parameter, so that means that the object passed as `options` won't be modified. The modified object is assigned back to `options`, but as it's just a function parameter that won't change the reference in the calling environment. If you wanted to do that, you'd have to return the value and assign it in the calling environment.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.assign` sets properties on the object you give it as its first argument; it also returns that same object. So in your first example, since you're passing `option` as the first argument, it gets updated with new/updated properties. In your second example, you're not passing it as the first argument, it's just one of the "source" objects to read properties from, so it isn't updated.

---

If your confusion is why the *assignment* didn't change `opts`, it's because assigning to the parameter doesn't have any effect on anything outside the function. E.g.:

```
function foo(a) {
    a = 42;
}
var x = 67;
foo(x);
console.log(x); // Still 67
```

That's because `foo(x)` reads the *value* of `x` and passes it into `foo`. There is no connection between `a` and `x` other than that `a`'s value originally came from `x`.

It's exactly the same with `opts`/`options`. `mergeOptions(opts, passedOptions)` reads the **value** of `opts`, which is an object reference, and passes that value into `mergeOptions`. There's no ongoing connection between that value and `opts`. The object reference points to the object, not to the variable `opts`.