# Object.assign(...as) changes input parameter

Tags: javascript

`Object.assign(...as)` appears to change the input parameter. Example:

```
const as = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];
const aObj = Object.assign(...as);
```

I deconstruct an array of object literals as parameter of the assign function.
I omitted `console.log` statements. Here's the stdout from node 13.7:

> as before assign:  [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]

> aObj:  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

> as after assign:  [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]

The reader may notice that `as` first element has been changed in an entire.
Changing a new array `bs` elements to an immutable object (using `freeze`)

```
const bs = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];
[0, 1, 2].map(k => Object.freeze(bs[k]));
const bObj = Object.assign(...bs);
```

leads to an error:

> TypeError: Cannot add property b, object is not extensible
> at Function.assign (<anonymous>)

Which indicates the argument is indeed being changed.

What really confounds me is that even binding my array, `cs`, by currying it to a function (I think you call this a closure in JS)

```
const cs = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];
const f = (xs) => Object.assign(...xs);
const g = () => f(cs);                            

const cObj = g();
```

returns:

> cs before assign:  [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
> cObj:  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
> cs after assign:  [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]

What went wrong here? And how may one safely use `Object.assign` without wrecking its first argument?

Comment: You should use `Object.assign({}, ...as)` since it modifies the first argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object.assign() - weird behaviour need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149560/object-assign-weird-behaviour-need-explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` is not a pure function, it writes over its first argument `target`.

Here is its entry on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Object.assign(target, ...sources)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *target*
>
> The target object — what to apply the sources’ properties to, which is returned after it is  modified.
>
> *sources*
>
> The source object(s) — objects containing the properties you want to apply.
>
> **Return value**
>
> The target object.

The key phrase is "[the target] is returned *after it is modified*". To avoid this, pass an empty object literal `{}` as first argument:

```
const aObj = Object.assign({}, ...as);
```

Comment: Also there's no "curried function" here.

Comment: About your open question: try [immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: @Pointy I concede that is a very muddy statement. It is pretty obvious that the assignment of variable to reference was not changed (const as...) However, when we peel off that level of abstraction we do have no functions in any stricter sense whatsoever. Since Object.assig is obviously not pure, I'm at a loss of finding a concise phrase for a method that meddles with its input _and_ returns it. When you help me to find a more suitable 'deragoratory term' ;-) for it, I shall happily edit it :-)

Comment: Well it's absolutely no different than any other function. Any function can make modifications to an object passed in as a parameter (unless the object is frozen of course).

Comment: @Pointy (2) However, there may be a curried function. And that's when it is relevant. For instance, look at the example in the Q. Let `f' = xs => y => f(xs)`, f' is thus a function that's constant in y but has two arguments `f : [a] -> b -> { a }`. Now curry with `g' =  f'(as)` and then `g' : b -> {a}` is a function with one argument it is constant in. Now I'm not certain with nomenclatura and defs, we may extend the same principle to functions f and g, with one and zero arguments, respectively. I think you tend to call them closures.

Comment: Another term that I more commonly associate with side effects is [procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_(computer_science)). But you really just should write "*…is not a pure function*".

Comment: "Any function can make modifications to an object passed in as a parameter." Yes indeed. But that's a genuinely bad thing. Even back in Fortran 77 that was frowned upon. Functions (with side-effects) oughtn't touch their arguments, use `procedure` to do so. The fact that `Object.assign` also returned the modified first argument is extra misleading. Now, your comment pointed me to why one might to do it. Since writing `o = Object.assign(o, ...as);` binds `o` to a new object (changes reference), while in `const rubbishO = Object.assign(o, ...as)` changes it without changing the bind of o.

Comment: @Bergi I thought it were trivially clear that it is not a _pure_ function, ie without side effects. I was thinking in the terms of procedure vs function. Now, since it gaves rise for more controversy than it is worth, how to edit it out. Let's try... ps.: nice to see you here Bergi, I read quite a couple of your answers  here over the course of the last weeks. Good job at getting present answers to old questions that had only clumsy pre ES6 code as answers.

Comment: @gschenk Just press the [[edit]] button below the answer :-)