# Object.assign() modifies its parameters?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why the 'data' value is being modified in `test.js` file.

> ```
> // data.js
> export default {
> a: 1,
> b: 2,
> c: 3,
> };
> ```

> // test.js
>
> ```
> import data from "./data";
>
> console.log({ data }); // {a:1,b:2,c:4}
> const modif1 = Object.assign(data, { c: 4 }); 
> console.log({ modif1 }); // {a:1,b:2,c:4}
> ```

I wasn't able to reproduce it in codepen, but here's a repo:
https://github.com/bmichalowski/shards
path to file: `./src/stories/PropsBug`

I don't think a react or storybook has anything to do with it, so I don't tag it.

**Edit:**

In this jsfiddle, the behavior is as expected.
https://jsfiddle.net/83xsdomb/ However, my code has a different order. Why is the `date` displayed modified when it is modified theoretically *after* it is displayed?

Comment: Because the first parameter is the "target" of the modification.

Comment: Why does _data.js_ show `c:3` and yet you're logging it as `c:4`?

Comment: Pretty straight forward: [Read the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Or [Object.assign() - weird behaviour need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41149560/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object.

> Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties overwrite earlier ones.

Essentially, it modifies the first object passed to it, and returns the same object.

You can avoid this by passing `{}` as the first parameter.

```js
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const modif1 = Object.assign({}, data, { c: 4 }); 
console.log(data);
console.log(modif1);
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I missed an empty object.